# Display session value in ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

i just started with the basics of AngularJS and tried to show UserName via ng-bind method in a modal popup, but i'm not able to display UserName in the output from my MVC View. My Angularjs code is here

```
<div class="row" ng-app="">

//I was not knowing how to store UserName from the session into ng-init, so did like this. Not sure whether its correct.
 @{          
     //Here i am storing Username coming from session into my string variable
     string UserName = ((Elearning.Models.tbl_Student)Session["Student"]).UserName;  

    //Here i have used mvc Hidden to use ng-init to store this UserName
    @Html.Hidden("Name", UserName, new { ng_init = UserName })
}

//Here is my button where i am going to call my popup
<input type="button" value="Preview" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPreview" />

//Here is my Bootstrap popup to show ng-init value 
<div id="modalPreview" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dtModalForget" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">                    
                <div class="modal-body ">
                    <p ng-bind=UserName></p>                        
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

My problem is when i click on Preview button, it will show popup but there it won't display Username. Can anyone please tell me how to show Username in popup. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng_init should be assigning UserName like below

```
@Html.Hidden("Name", UserName, new { ng_init = "UserName='"+ UserName + "'" });
```

and ng-bind as below

```
<p ng-bind="UserName"></p>
```